# Как правильно в модели базы данных связывать (хранить) данные о наблюдений за птицами?

Tags: sql, база-данных, модель-данных

Делаю базу данных наблюдений за птицами. Выделил отдельные "справочники", возникла проблема теперь с объединением этих данных. Т.е. нужна таблица, которая бы хранила результат наблюдений:

Примеры данных наблюдений:

- 10.10.18 Андрей наблюдает среднюю стаю
- 11.10.18 Дмитрий наблюдает большую стаю, в стае имеются вороны, сороки
- 12.10.18 Дмитрий наблюдает среднюю стаю и большую стаю
- 12.10.18 Антон наблюдает ворон, аистов.

Выделил таблицы:

- Виды птиц
- Размер стаи
- Тип объекта (Стая/Птица)
- Источник наблюдений

Нужна таблица, в которой фиксировалась бы данные наблюдений.

1. Не могу сообразить, как это сделать. Как будто я что-то упустил.
2. Не могу понять, как сделать так, чтобы можно было фиксировать:

   - размер стаи
   - размер стаи + виды птиц в стае
   - так и отдельно виды птиц

Подскажите пожалуйста.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спросите на форуме rbcu.ru у Ильи Уколова схему его базы ;) Но у него покруче немного.

Comment: Можно создать таблицу `Наблюдения(ID_Наблюдения,дата_наблюдения,ID_наблюдателя, дополнительная_информация)` и таблицу расширение `Детальные_наблюдения(ID_наблюдения(из Наблюдения),ID_обекта(может быть как стаей с размером, так и видом птицы))`

Comment: @Viktorov  ...ID_обекта(может быть как стаей с размером, так и видом птицы), а что это за тип поля в котором можно выбрать стаю с размером так и вид птицы???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вам нужно завести еще одну таблицу `Факты`, которая связана с таблицей наблюдений как 1 ко многим:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В этом случае каждая запись в таблице факты с идентификатором конкретного наблюдения будет означать *что там увидели еще*

Если в таблице `Факты` будут 4 записи с одинаковым идентификатором наблюдения со ссылками на размер стаи, на вид птицы вороны, аисты и сороки. Тогда это будет трактоваться так:

```
11.10.18 Дмитрий наблюдает большую стаю, в стае имеются вороны, аисты и сороки
```

Comment: Я бы вынес из таблицы Факты 'id птица' в отдельную таблицу которую бы связал бы один ко многим с таблицей Факты. Тем самым таблица Факты станет соответствовать третьей нормальной форме(то есть не будет дублей значений полей относящихся к одному наблюеднию), а также можно будет понять наблюдали в момент одну большую стаю содержащую несколько видов птиц или же несколько стай содержащих определенные виды.

Comment: @GreyGoblin на диаграмме понял как это сделать. А если физическую модель строить, тогда получается что в таблице Птицы, будут реквизиты Id Факта, Id птицы, Наименование птицы. Тогда получается, что ID факта дублируется сразу в нескольких таблицах

Comment: @GreyGoblin если птицу может быть указана а может и нет, то получается связь 1 к 0...*   Так?

Comment: @Kirumit таблица Птицы не должна содержать ссылок на факты. По сути это просто справочник птиц. В минимальном виде будет содержать id и наименование птицы. Таблица о которой я говорил связывает Факты и Птицы. То есть содержит id факта и id птицы. Соответственно записей в ней для каждого факта будет по числу видов птиц в факте или ни одной, если информации о птицах нет. Дубли id о которых вы пишете - это нормально. Это же ключевые поля по которым производятся связывание таблиц.

Comment: @GreyGoblin я вас понял. 1) Тогда и стаи мне так надо наверное сделать? Создать еще одну таблицу для связки факта и стаи.  Пример: 10.10.2018 наблюдается: Стая средняя, стая большая                                                     
 2) А надо ли как-то связывать стаю и птиц? Пример:  В средней стае наблюдаются вороны, сороки

Comment: @Kirumit 1. Не нужно. В данной модели факт - это наблюдение одной стаи с определенными птицами. Будут две стаи, значит будут два факта. 2. в предложенной модели id стаи - это ссылка на таблицу хранящую тип стаи. В минимальном варианте id и наименование типа стаи(большая, маленькая...). В данной модели между таблицей типов стай и Птицы прямая связь не нужна.

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужно создать таблицу "Объект наблюдения" в которой создать поля для храниеия ID стаи, ID птицы, размер стаи, тип объекта (стая или птица). Потом ID этой таблицы вписавать в "Данные наблюдений".

Comment: а как показать. что размер стаи указывается если только в поле Тип объекта=Стая?

Comment: добавьте поле ID размера стаи

Comment: Спасибо за ответы. Хотел бы уточнить, надо хранить данные о множестве наблюдаемых стай, наблюдаемых стаях и множестве птиц в стае, а также наблюдаемых множеств птиц за один период времени наблюдения. Т.е. в Объекте наблюдения будут находится множество данных о птицах и стаях? Так?

Comment: Получается так: Наблюдение (Дата, Объект наблюдения), Объект наблюдения (ID наблюдения, ID размер стаи, ID птицы), Так чтоли?

Comment: Не совсем так, ведь у вас уже есть "Данные наблюдений" и это то же самое что "Наблюдение".

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, наблюдения лучше сделать немного более детальными.

1. Одна запись наблюдения - один вид. Также добавить поля "количество", "пол" и "возраст". Возраст точно определить нельзя, но птенцы всегда отличаются от родителей, а иногда и взрослые птицы долго не меняют подростковую окраску. Например, бакланы и лебеди в возрасте около года примерно отличаются по окраске от взрослых, но не отличаются по размеру. Значения там будут примерно такие:

   - птенец
   - подросток
   - взрослая особь

   В базах наблюдений, с которыми я имел дело, обычно какое-то такое поле есть.
2. Если точное количество неизвестно, можно добавить справочное поле "размер стаи" с вариантами, например, `1 - 10`, `10 - 50`, `50 - 100`, `больше 100`. И заполнять либо точное количество, либо приблизительное. Но обычно с подсчетом проблем не возникает: на практике большинство наблюдателей просто делает фото, а дома, в спокойной обстановке, вооружившись фотошопом, пересчитывает.
3. Ну и дополнительные поля типа даты, времени, координат и т. п.

Это будет сущность `"наблюдение птицы"` (или `факт`, как Barmaley предложил), а несколько таких наблюдений, сделанных за один выезд "в поле", объединять в сущность `"наблюдение"`.

**UPD.** Добавлю схему:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И немного пояснений.

"Сессия наблюдений" (`observation_session`) - это один "заход". Например, наблюдатель Маша Иванова 01.01.2018 выехала в поле и два часа шла из пункта А в пункт Б, делая наблюдения. Этому событию соответствует одна запись в этой таблице.

Далее каждая встреченная во время этой сессии наблюдений птица заносится отдельной строкой в таблицу `observation`. Из справочников подтягиваются пояснения - какой вид, сколько птиц, и так далее. Если точное количество установить не удается, можно записывать приблизительное из справочника `bird_group`, но я честно говоря не представляю, что вы с ним потом будете делать. Потому что по факту это количество, но работать с полем как с числом вы не сможете, только делать оценки уровня "плюс-минус километр".

P. S. Бердвотчер-любитель со стажем, если что ;)

Comment: Это будет сущность "наблюдение птицы" (или факт, как Barmaley предложил), а несколько таких наблюдений, сделанных за один выезд "в поле", объединять в сущность "наблюдение"/// а как объединять? Что значит объединить в сущность "наблюдение"?

Comment: Связь "один ко многим", как между наблюдением и типом объекта в вашей схеме, например.

Comment: @Kirumit Держите схему.

Comment: спасибо огромное! Вопросы: 1. Почему в observation есть поле Дата и в observation_session также поле Дата? Непойму зачем дублировать и там и там поле Дата                                             2. Вы разработчик БД, как вас занесло и стали Бердвотчер-любители?:)))

Comment: 1. Дата в `observation_session` - это дата всего "мероприятия". А дата в `observation` сделана в основном для записи времени встречи конкретной птицы. В моем примере в тексте ответа `01.01.2018` - это дата для `observation_session`, а в `observation` будет `18:05, сорока, 3 штуки`, `18:12, дрозд, 2 штуки`, и т. д. Потом, когда наберется много результатов, можно будет делать обобщения типа "сороки после 7 вечера не встречаются, совы раньше девяти не охотятся" и т. п. 2) Есть такое слово - "хобби". Еще я (в разные периоды биографии) альпинист, аквариумист и "фотограф". Оно само так получается.

Comment: в нашем случае не фиксируется время наблюдения конкретной птицы. Только период. Пример: за время 10.08.18 10:00 до 10.08.18 20.00 зафиксировано:                                                         
Большие стаи птиц: сороки, грачи; Средняя стая птиц, аисты;  Вороны 2 штуки.                                                                         
А если у нас  не учитывается время наблюдения конкретной птицы, то как я понимаю нужно оставить дату только в одной из таблиц? Так? А в какой порекомендуете оставить эту дату? Наверное в сессии? Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Ну да, в таком случае только в сессии оставить.

Comment: еще возник вопрос, Бармалей, выше предложил  _"...я бы вынес из табл. Факты 'id птица' в отдельную таблицу которую бы связал 1..* с табл. Факты. Табл. Факты станет соответствовать 3 нормальной форме(не будет дублей значений полей относящихся к одному наблюдению), а также можно будет понять наблюдали в момент одну большую стаю содержащую..."_   Дмитрий, хотел бы узнать у вас мнение, вы человек с опытом разработки БД и орнитологией! Подскажите пожалуйста, в каком случае лучше применить ваш вариант, а в каком случае Бармалея?  Почему ваше решение не как у Бармалея?

Comment: Я честно говоря не понял, а чем мое решение принципиально отличается от его? Я только чуть подробнее расписал. То, что у него "Наблюдения", у меня `observation_session`, а то, что у него "Факты", у меня `observation`.

Comment: В случае когда птиц много в стае (пример: 11.08.2018 наблюдатось Андреем Средняя стая птиц в составе вороны, сороки. аиста), в его схеме в таблице Факты (observation) как я понял будет храниться 1 запись Наблюдений (observation_session) и множество записей в таблице Птицы. А по Вашей схеме в таблице  Факты будет множество записей наблюдений с одним значением птицы.  Так я понял, по крайне мере) Вот хотел узхнать ваше мнение в каких случаях применять лучше то решение, а в каких другое? ;)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80213/discussion-between-dmitry-and-kirumit).